# Android change textsize of textview which is inside a view pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-view, android-pageradapter

I have a text view inside a view pager with pager adapter. In my activity on click on a button I want to change text size of that textview. What I have tried so far

```
View view1 = (View) customPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(viewPager, viewPager.getCurrentItem());
            TextView textView = (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.tvPoem);
            textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, textView.getTextSize() + 1);
            customPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

And also tried

```
    ((TextView) viewPager.getChildAt(currentPagePosition).findViewById(R.id.tvPoem)).setTextSize(
                TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,
                ((TextView) viewPager.getChildAt(currentPagePosition).findViewById(R.id.tvPoem)).getTextSize() + 1);
        customPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        viewPager.invalidate();
```

Where currentPagePosition is the position I got from on page change listener. It is working fine on the first page. But Once I change my page, It's not working at all. I have debug my code and check currentPagePosition. It is returning the accurate position. I have also tried it on UIThread and on runnable with posted delay. Any help on this would be much appreciated . thanks

Comment: have you tried to set your on click listener in your pager adapter and apply the changes there . i mean do all the stuff in pager adapter plus if you wanna make a lot of changes you better use fragments here is the tutorial http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Comment: No. But I have done most of the work In activity. Can there be any workaround to do it in my activity?

Comment: Actually have to do some Database work on it also. So inside activity is more preferable. What u think?

Comment: it's is better to use fragments is these cases . just spend some time reading some tutorials and you will get familiar with fragments and how to use them in viewpager

Comment: what's wrong with doing work on database in a fragment ?